# Как сконвертировать Windows NT time format в обычную дату в GOlang?

Tags: алгоритм, golang, дата

Имеется ответ из MS AD о сроке действия УЗ в формате Windows NT time format. Нужно его сконвертировать в обычную дату (YYYY-MM-DD, к примеру). Готовых решений для GOlang, к сожалению, не нашел. Просьба подсказать как реализовать данную задачу.

Пример полученного ответа: 131805158950000000, что будет равно 2018-09-04 г., 6:24:55

Comment: Какая точность нужна? Секунды/миллисекунды/микросекунды?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример, взятый из пакета `syscall`:

```
const ntToUnixDiff = 116444736000000000

func ntToTime(ntt int64) time.Time {
    var nsec int64 = (ntt - ntToUnixDiff) * 100
    return time.Unix(0, nsec)
}
```

Код в `syscall`: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/76c45877c9e72ccc84db787dc08299e0182e0efb/src/syscall/types_windows.go#L351.

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/cgkFXEKX0KG.